# Why does adding integers to a string result in a string?

Tags: c#

I can't understand, why in the first write sentence 5 and 7 are numbers (so the output is **12**), but in the last write sentence 5 and 7 are `string`s (so the output is **57**). 
Is in the C# rule, that if the first thing in the Write sentence is `string`, also every other things are `string`?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{        
    class Program    
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
              Console.WriteLine( 5 + 7 );
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine( "?  " + 5 + 7 );

              Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on operator overloading.

Comment: its because of the order in which the arguments are combined, in the first case theres 2 numbers so they get added together. In the second case there string number number, so from left to right they combine the string to the number, which becomes string. So then its left with a string and a number which combined becomes a string

Comment: because `"? "+5` generates string

Comment: Wtf is this? i'm bothering to write a long answer and then I can't post it? Seriously?!

Comment: @Neme Its a duplicate, we don't need the same information replicated more than once. The posted answer was there before question closure. Sometimes life isn't fair :(

Comment: @Neme You can vote to reopen it if you feel you have an answer that is better than the duplicate.

Comment: @DStanley No; it's still a duplicate and shouldn't be reopened.  He could post his answer at the other question though.

Comment: @NobodyNada You can certainly _vote_ to reopen it and argue a case.  I agree that it's unlikely to be reopened but it is still an option.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I feel like this question was more about operator associativity and tried to make a detailed answer explaining the differences between this and adding the integers first. Questions are almost never exactly the same and may view the same thing from a different perspective. I see no point in blocking answers, since multiple answers the same exact question (not just a similar one) are not prohibited either. Also it seems unfair to me that whoever gets the chance to post first, "wins".

Comment: @Neme I'm not going to argue with you on first post "winning" not being fair (though it is at -3, so not sure if you are missing out on much). In my opinion (at least so far) the confusion is how + works when a string is involved (and a comment from the OP on the answer reinforces this). That question is answered by the duplicate; as far as why we close duplicates, there is plenty of material on meta. I can see the confusion regarding operator precedence, but it doesn't seem to be the crux of the problem.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for all the answers.                            BradleyDotNET, to someone who already knows and understands C# is everything clear perfectly, but try to imagine, that things for the beginners are much harder. I'm new here and now I would like to joine this post or question with the old one "string = string + int: What's behind the scenes?", but is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it is an issue of rules. It is more the way the compiler asserts the priority and precedence of operators.

`Int` is also a class with methods and a certain implementation of operators. Basically you can imagine that if on the right side of the operator there is an integer both numbers will be added. In the first case the first argument is an integer `5` so the compiler will choose to take the implementation of the integer operator.

`string` is also a class with its own implementation of the `+` operator, which will concatenate the item on the right hand side of the operator. And since every object has a `ToString` method the compiler calls the `ToString` method of `Int` in the second case, transforms the number into a string and concatenates them. Because in the second case on the left hand side there is a `string` and the compiler takes the implementation of the `string` overload of the `+` operator.

You can influence the outcome by using `( )` because they have a higher precedence. So the expression within the parentheses will be evaluated first:

```
Console.WriteLine( "?  " + ( 5 + 7 ));
```

This time the `Int` implementation of the `+` operator overload will be executed first and the one of `String` afterwards, and you should get your expected `12` as output.